# Is there a simple way to simulate lag with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

is there a way to simulate lag with Meteor? Perhaps something that would delay all calls by say, 300ms?

Comment: Why? I'm sure there's a valid reason, I just can't think of one

Comment: Swadq: testing the impact of latency without having to resort to a 3rd party proxy like fiddler.

Comment: You could deploy it and use it, that would have latency ;p

Comment: I understand your comment was tongue-in-cheek Patrick, but I hope to have some form of formal control over the amount of latency in question :)

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in `publish` using:

```
Meteor._sleepForMs(5000); // sleeps for 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess I'm a bit late for the party, but here's a better solution:

There are basically two parts to this question. One is, how to delay Meteor WebSocket ([SockJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs)) writes and one is how to delay HTTP traffic ([connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect)). You'll need to add both of the following snippets to your server-side code in order to delay *all* traffic sent from the Meteor server.

### WebSocket

The hard part was overwriting the WebSocket `write` to delay it with a `setTimeout`:

```
(function () {
  // Set the delay you want
  var timeout = 3000
  // stream_server abstracts sockJS the DDP-Server talks to it. 
  var streamServer = Meteor.server.stream_server
  // The connect event listener
  var standardConnect = streamServer.server._events.connection

  // Overwrite the default event-handler
  streamServer.server._events.connection = function (socket) {
    // Overwrite the writes to the socket
    var write = socket.write
    socket.write = function () {
      var self = this
      var args = arguments
      // Add a delay
      setTimeout(function () {
        // Call the normal write methods with the arguments passed to this call
        write.apply(self, args)
      }, timeout)
    }
    // Call the normal handler after overwritting the socket.write function
    standardConnect.apply(this, arguments)
  }
})()
```

### HTTP

With [connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) it's pretty straight forward:

```
// Add a simple connect handler, wich calls the next handler after a delay
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function (req, res, next) {
  return setTimeout(next, timeout)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about all calls, but you can use Futures to add a lag on the server, that way you can see latency compensation in action.

In a meteor method for example, you can

```
Meteor.methods({
  post: function(post) {
    post.title = post.title + (this.isSimulation ? '(client)' : '(server)');

    // wait for 5 seconds
    if (! this.isSimulation) {
      var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
      var future = new Future();
      Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        future.ret();
      }, 5 * 1000); // 5 seconds
      future.wait();
    }
    var postId = Posts.insert(post);
    return postId;
  }
});
```

This will show the post being inserted with (client) appended to the end, and then 5 seconds later will get the update from the server and post's title will end with (server)

Comment: Thank you, yes that's what I'm using now, method by method - would like to indeed see it across all methods everywhere. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you want simulate the lag in the subscriptions you can do the next:

```
Meteor.publish('collection', function(params) {
  Meteor._sleepForMs(2000); // Sleep for 2 seconds    
  return CollectionX.find(params.query,params.projection);
});
```